# Received unexpected output in MRUnit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mrunit

I'm getting the following MRUnit error:

> ERROR mrunit.TestDriver: **Received unexpected output (60, mrdp.MyCustomClass@73207f36)**
>
> ERROR mrunit.TestDriver: **Missing expected output (60, mrdp.MyCustomClass@6f73cf45) at position 0**

I've created a `MyCustomClass` which implements `Writable`, and has 4 int attributes. This is the output Value of my Mapper.

The following is the code of the mapper's MRUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testMapper() throws IOException {
    MyCustomClass result = new MyCustomClass();
    result.setAttr1(1);
    result.setAttr2(0);
    result.setAttr3(0);
    result.setAttr4(0);

    mapDriver.withInput(new LongWritable(1), new Text("60,5596,1,256"));
    mapDriver.addOutput(new Text("60"), result);
    mapDriver.runTest();
}
```

My Mapper should call its setter `setAttr1(1)`, when locating the "1" in the `new Text("60,5596,1,256")` here above.

How can I test for this result with a custom class (with several attributes)? The job execution is successful, I just don't know how to make the MRUnit test work.

```
$ hadoop fs -cat patterns/minmaxcount/outuserprefs/part*
23  mrdp.MyCustomClass@4cf15f6c
60  mrdp.MyCustomClass@4cf15f6c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `equals()` and `hascode()` for your custom classes if you want to test for equality. If you don't, there's no way to test for "semantic equality". The default `Object` methods will be used. That is what you are facing. For further discussion, see [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Below a simple JUnit test using a custom class `CustomClass`. I commented out the the `equals` and `hashcode`. If you run the test, it will fail, with a similar message to what you are receiving. If you remove the comments and run it, it will pass.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CustomClass {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    @Test
    public void testEqaulity() {
        CustomClass clazz1 = new CustomClass();
        clazz1.setFirstName("Stack");
        clazz1.setLastName("Overflow");

        CustomClass clazz2 = new CustomClass();
        clazz2.setFirstName("Stack");
        clazz2.setLastName("Overflow");

        assertEquals(clazz1, clazz2);
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CustomClass other = (CustomClass) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    */
}
```

If you don't have experience or knowledge in implementing these methods, most IDE have the option to create them for you.

- Eclipse: right click on class -> Source -> Generate equals and hashcode
- Netbeans: right click on source editor -> Insert Code -> equals() hashcode()

In both cases, you need to select the properties you want to include (check) in the equals and hashcode. These are the only two IDEs I use :-)

Comment: Thank you, indeed your answer helped me to find the "assertThat()" for MRUnit tests. Found some examples in http://java.dzone.com/articles/testing-mapreduce-mrunit